# ajax calling twice with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ajax is calling twice in my below code i checked it with Fiddler as well firebug..

I read all related question but dint found solution.... below is my code..

I also checked onclick event it also firing twice..

```
 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqmd.css" />

<script src="js/jm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
         <body>    

       </body>
 <script language="javascript">

    function pp() {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "cont.aspx/getP",
            data: "{gt: '',cid: ''}",
            success: function(r) {
                alert('test');
            }
        });
    }

    setTimeout("pp()", 2000);
  </script>
```

Comment: You should add the element that is supposed to trigger the click event to be able to give a better answer

Comment: i want it to run after 2 sec. of page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var t='';
 function pp() {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "cont.aspx/getP",
            data: "{gt: '',cid: ''}",
            success: function(r) {
                alert('test');
            }
        });
 clearTimeout(t);
    }

 t= setTimeout("pp()", 2000);
```

Comment: Thank tanducar .. it is working fine... but onchange still firing twice.. $('#btn1').change(function() {
        pp();
    });

Comment: check e.type  before you call the pp() function. $('#btn1').change(function(e)  { e.type.. pp(); })

Answer (score 0):

What about setting a boolean value to true after the ajax call is done, if the value have been changed, then it will not run. Try this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var j;
    function pp() {
        if (j !== true) {
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "cont.aspx/getP",
                data: "{gt: '',cid: ''}",
                success: function(r) {
                    alert('test');
                }
            });
         }
            j = true;
        }

        setTimeout("pp()", 2000);
      </script>
```